# How to install or uninstall gcloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, installation, gcloud, uninstallation, google-cloud-sdk

I follow all the steps from [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install).

At the final step where I run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk`, I get:

```
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/berglh/pulseaudio-a2dp/ubuntu impish InRelease            
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease                                  
Hit:4 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease [110 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports InRelease [101 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease [110 kB]
Fetched 321 kB in 2s (178 kB/s) 
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
google-cloud-sdk is already the newest version (372.0.0-0).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

But, when I run `gcloud` it says

```
Command 'gcloud' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo snap install google-cloud-cli  # version 371.0.0, or
sudo snap install google-cloud-sdk  # version 371.0.0
See 'snap info <snapname>' for additional versions.
```

I add

```
source $HOME/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc
source $HOME/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc
```

at the end of my ~/.bashrc

I run  `source ~/.bashrc`

I get:

```
bash: /home/nitin/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc: No such file or directory
bash: /home/nitin/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc: No such file or directory
```

I try to run `gcloud`

I get:

```
Command 'gcloud' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo snap install google-cloud-cli  # version 371.0.0, or
sudo snap install google-cloud-sdk  # version 371.0.0
See 'snap info <snapname>' for additional versions.
```

Since, I cannot run `gcloud`, I cannot even run

```
gcloud info --format='value(installation.sdk_root)'
 gcloud info --format='value(config.paths.global_config_dir)'
```

and hence cannot complete the steps given [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/uninstall-cloud-sdk) to uninstall the cloud

PLEASE HELP ME SET UP GCLOUD ON MY MACHINE

Comment: Please do not use uppercase since it is interpreted as you're shouting

Comment: I am just angry with myself for having decided to use google for my cloud needs. Everything is soo much more intuitive with azure and aws. And it works with aws and azure. I had made a point to never choose google after I saw how much time I had wasted on tensorflow and pytorch was so much more intuitive. At any rate, I guess you are right. I will remember that

Comment: Just to be sure, which linux distribution are you using? I guess maybe ubuntu/debian

Comment: yes, you are right! I am on ubuntu 21.10

Comment: Use the **find** command to locate where gcloud is installed and then add it to your PATH.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 options on how to install gcloud CLI by checking if your distribution supports `signed-by`option. You mentioned that you're using **Ubuntu 21.10**, meaning that `signed-by` option is supported, according to this [Ubuntu manuals documentation](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/en/man5/sources.list.5.html).

I have replicated the steps and only selected options which supports the `signed-by` option.

Upon further reading, `apt-key` will be deprecated soon, according to this [link](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/01/apt-key-is-deprecated-how-to-add.html). Transitioning to `signed-by` would be a better option.

I've used the following commands as they worked on my end:

```
 1. sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates gnupg
 2. echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list
 3. curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -
 4. sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk
 5. gcloud init
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Run these 5 commands to install **"gcloud"** for **Debian/Ubuntu**:

---

```
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates gnupg -y
```

```
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main"  | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list
```

```
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -
```

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-cli
```

***"--console-only"** is really important to open a browser properly and you can also use **"--no-launch-browser"** instead of **"--console-only"**.

```
gcloud init --console-only
```

---

I concatenated these 5 commands above with **"&&"** as shown below so that you can run only one command:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates gnupg -y &&
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main"  | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list &&
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add - && 
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-cli && 
gcloud init --console-only
```

After running the command above, you will be asked as shown below then, input **"y"** then, press **Enter**:

> You must log in to continue. Would you like to log in (Y/n)?  y

Then, one URL is displayed and you are asked for **a "verification code"** which you can get from the URL by allowing **Google Cloud SDK**  to access your Google Account:

> Go to the following link in your browser:
>
> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=32555940559.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&scope=openid+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fappengine.admin+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcompute+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Faccounts.reauth&state=pDDwd21KWSbLPwjJ0MCX7JCDwePBzR&prompt=consent&access_type=offline&code_challenge=vZ-2U2YLwHtQPPAVSDjzrfi2uoke4laUwwnOhkOL064&code_challenge_method=S256
>
> Enter verification code:

Then, you need to go to the URL above using your browser then, choose one of your google accounts:

[image]

Then, press **"Allow"**:

[image]

Then, copy **the verification code** as shown below:

[image]

Then, paste **the verification code** then, press **Enter**:

> Go to the following link in your browser:
>
> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=32555940559.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&scope=openid+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fappengine.admin+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcompute+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Faccounts.reauth&state=pDDwd21KWSbLPwjJ0MCX7JCDwePBzR&prompt=consent&access_type=offline&code_challenge=vZ-2U2YLwHtQPPAVSDjzrfi2uoke4laUwwnOhkOL064&code_challenge_method=S256
>
> Enter verification code: 4/1AX4XfWg7oIOraXFuEGLApi3knvBqvqFgY8bA_6Yj8_osTd4f_FwzrvhicS0

Then, you could log in then, choose one of your projects then, press **Enter**:

> You are logged in as: [myappdev@gmail.com].
>
> Pick cloud project to use:
> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfEBg.png) myproject-817133
> [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDZxe.png) yourproject-339620
> [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kr2pb.png) Enter a project ID
> [4] Create a new project
> Please enter numeric choice or text value (must exactly match list item):  1

Finally, choosing a default Compute Region and Zone (Optional) finishes the installation:

> Do you want to configure a default Compute Region and Zone? (Y/n)?